# Skip the SetUp method only for a particular test in NUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I have a test where I do not need to run the `SetUp` method (attributed with `[SetUp]`) before running the test. I need the `SetUp` method to be run for other tests.

Is there a different attribute that can be used or a non-attribute-based way to achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should create a new class for that test which has only the setup (or lack of setup) that it needs.

Alternatively, you could unfactor the setup code into a method that all the other tests call, but I don't recommend this approach.

Comment: If i want this to be in same class how can i do that??

Answer (score 26):

You could also add a category and inspect the category list in your setup:

```cs
public const string SKIP_SETUP = "SkipSetup"; 

[SetUp]
public void Setup(){
   if (!CheckForSkipSetup()){
        // Do Setup stuff
   }
}

private static bool CheckForSkipSetup() {
    ArrayList categories = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test
       .Properties["_CATEGORIES"] as ArrayList;

    bool skipSetup = categories != null && categories.Contains( SKIP_SETUP );
    return skipSetup ;
}

[Test]
[Category(SKIP_SETUP)]
public void SomeTest(){
    // your test code
}
```

Comment: @DebendraDash '_CATEGORIES' is called 'Category' in more recent versions of NUnit. This is the kind of thing that can easily happen when relying on library internals.

Comment: I spent a half hour with this. Be aware: Category is not queryable when using [TestCase] attribute. (bug) https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2107.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the main `SetUp` in a base class:

```cs
[SetUp]
public virtual void SetUp()
{
  // Set up things here
}
```

...and then override it in the class where you have the tests that should not run the `SetUp` code:

```cs
[SetUp]
public override void SetUp()
{
  // By not calling base.SetUp() here, the base SetUp will not run
}
```

Comment: Specifically in nunit "You may define a SetUp method in the base class and another in the derived class. NUnit will call base class SetUp methods before those in the derived classes." [nunit doc](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-Attribute). I haven't tested this myself but it sounds like the base SetUp() will still be called.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that I suggest for accomplishing what you want.

```cs
public const string SKIP_SETUP = "SkipSetup";
```

Now add the following method:

```cs
private static bool CheckForSkipSetup()
{               
    var categories = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test?.Properties["Category"];

    bool skipSetup = categories != null && categories.Contains("SkipSetup");
    return skipSetup;
}
```

Now check the condition as follows:

```cs
[SetUp]
public async Task Dosomething()
{
    if (!CheckForSkipSetup())
    {

    }
}
```

Use these in test cases as follows:

```cs
[Test]
[Category(SKIP_SETUP)]
public async Task Mywork()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that, it would involve knowing what test was about to run which I don't think is possible.

I'd suggest you put it within a different [TestFixture]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I suggest for accomplishing what you want:

```cs
public const string SKIP_SETUP = "SkipSetup";

private static bool CheckForSkipSetup()
{
    string category = string.Empty;
    var categoryKeys = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Keys.ToList();

    if (categoryKeys != null && categoryKeys.Any())
        category = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get(categoryKeys[0].ToString()) as string;

    bool skipSetup = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category) && category.Equals(SKIP_SETUP)) ? true : false;

    return skipSetup;
}

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    // Your setup code
}

[Test]
public void WithoutSetupTest()
{
    // Code without setup
}

[Test]
[Category(SKIP_SETUP)]
public void CodeWithSetupTest()
{
    // Code that require setup
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be buggy. (1) Attribute at the wrong test method (2) No call of the check method in `Setup()`.

Answer (score 0):

Per @MiGro answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245934/nunit-how-to-skip-test-setup-to-call-for-particular-unit-test-case) I did it by using another test namespace with it's own `[OneTimeSetUp]` with a different implementation for the classes that I wanted to start to test differently to others.